# Little help with some field arithmetic problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, cauchy-sequences

Let $K$ be a complete field with $\operatorname{char}(K) = 0$ and a non trivial ultrametric absolute value $||$,
Such that $K$ is a metric space.

Let $z$ a transcendental element over $K$.

We define $K\{z\} = \left\{ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} {a_n z^n} \mid a_n \in K , {a_n}  \rightarrow 0 \right\} $

Let $a \in K$ such that $|a| < 1$, and $f(z) \in K\{z\}$

How can one show that also $f(z+a) \in K\{z\}$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Elements of $K\{z\} $ are exactly power series that converge in the closed unit disk. Now, it's a property of ultrametric spaces that any point in the interior of a ball is its center.